# Prove $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} n (\log (n))^p a_n = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

There is a famous theorem by Olivier that says that if $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_n$ converges, $a_n >0$ and $(na_n)_n$ is a monotone decreasing sequence, then $n \log(n) a_n$ converges to $0$.

Is there a way to relax the hypothesis "$(n a_n)_n$ is monotone decreasing sequence" ?

For instance, is it true that if $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_n$ converges, $a_n >0$, then $n (\log(n))^p a_n$ converges to $0$ for some $p>0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

No for your example. Take $a_{n^4}=\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$, and $a_n=2^{-n}$ if $n$ is not a fourth power. The $a_n$ are positive with a finite sum, yet $\sqrt{n}a_n$ isn’t even bounded.

Comment: thanks for your examples !

Answer (score 1):

Not true. Take any sequence $n_k$ increasing to $\infty$ so fast that $\sum_k \frac 1 {\ln(n_k)} <\infty$. Let $a_n=\frac 1 {n^{2}}$ if $n \neq n_k$ for any $k$ and $a_n=\frac  1 {\ln (n)}$ if $n =n_k$. Then $na_n(\ln n)^{p} \to \infty$ for every $p >0$.